# MPMoviePlayerController audio only after application became active

Tags: objective-c, ios, video, mpmovieplayercontroller

I use `MPMoviePlayerController` in my application and when I tap the home button and then open application again, the player continues playback, but only the audio. Instead of the video, the user sees a black screen.

This bug is only on the device (iOS 5.0, maybe earlier versions too). On the simulator it's OK.

Any ideas?

Code that creates the `MPMoviePlayerController` instance and adds it to view:

```
if (!self.moviePlayerController) {
    MPMoviePlayerController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL];
    if (player) 
    {
        /* Save the movie object. */
        [self setMoviePlayerController:player];

        /* Register the current object as an observer for the movie
         notifications. */
        [self installMovieNotificationObservers];

        player.shouldAutoplay = YES;
        player.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
        player.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFit;
        player.useApplicationAudioSession = NO;
        [player setContentURL:movieURL];
        [player prepareToPlay];
        if ([player respondsToSelector:@selector(setAllowsAirPlay:)]) {
            [player setAllowsAirPlay:YES];
        }
        [player setMovieSourceType:sourceType];
        [[player view] setFrame:[self.view bounds]];

        [self.view addSubview: [player view]];
        [self.view sendSubviewToBack:[player view]];
        [player release];
    }
}
```

movieURL - is link to mp4 of this form: http://host.domain/filename.mp4
maybe `MPMoviePlayerController` not correctly works with mp4 source type over http?

**Solution**

In this case, all is well:

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActiveNotification:(NSNotification*)notification {    
    if (self.moviePlayerController.playbackState == MPMoviePlaybackStatePlaying) {
        self.playerState = PlayerStatePlaying;
    } else if (self.moviePlayerController.playbackState == MPMoviePlaybackStatePaused) {
        self.playerState = PlayerStatePaused;
    self.playbackTimeBeforeBackground = self.moviePlayerController.currentPlaybackTime;
    [self.moviePlayerController pause];
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActiveNotification:(NSNotification*)notification {
self.moviePlayerController.currentPlaybackTime = -1;    
    if (self.playerState & PlayerStatePlaying) {
        [self performSelector:@selector(startPlayerAfterDelayPause:) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.2];
    } else if (self.playerState & PlayerStatePaused) {
        [self performSelector:@selector(startPlayerAfterDelayPause:) withObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] afterDelay:0.2];
    }
}

- (void)startPlayerAfterDelayPause:(NSNumber *)isPause{
    self.moviePlayerController.currentPlaybackTime = self.playbackTimeBeforeBackground;
    if ([isPause boolValue] == YES) {
        [self.moviePlayerController pause];
    } else {
        [self.moviePlayerController play];
    }
}
```

Comment: on the device with iOS 5.1 video playing normally

Comment: Can you maybe post the code that creates the `MPMoviePlayerController` instance and adds it to your view, as well as any code that interacts with it? For example, code that pauses it when the application resigns active?

Comment: I edited post. When application resign and begin active - I do not do anything

Comment: You should add your fix as an answer to your question and accept it (instead of answering it within your question).

Answer (score 0):

you try this code:

```
NSString *path=[bundle pathForResource:@"ImageHomeAnimation" ofType:@"mp4"];

MPMoviePlayerController *mp = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]];

 self.player1= mp;//[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]];
    [mp release];
    self.player1.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, -20, 320,480);
    self.player1.view.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
   [self.view addSubview:self.player1.view];
    self.player1.fullscreen=YES;
   [self.player1 setRepeatMode:MPMovieRepeatModeNone];
   self.player1.controlStyle=MPMovieControlStyleNone;
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
 addObserver:self
 selector:@selector(movieFinishedCallback)  name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
 object:self.player1];
   [self.player1 prepareToPlay];
   [self.player1 play];

-(void)movieFinishedCallback
{

[self.player1.view removeFromSuperview];

}
```